# Convert JavaScript /[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g to Java

Tags: java, javascript, expression

How can I covert the following JavaScript regEx to Java regex?
/[^A-Za-z0-9+/\=]/g
Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what was the result? How are you using it in Javascript?

Comment: what makes you think both regexes are different?

Comment: I don't speak JavaScript.  What does the above actually do?  Can you provide some examples?

Comment: You have to escape the \ in Java, so replace all your \ with \\

Comment: Actually, do you need to escape at all inside a character class? (With some, other, exceptions, such as `^`)

Comment: @keyser No, you do not actually. And as far as I remember you don't have to escape ^ either, you simply put it as the last character. But don't quote me on that.

Comment: _" you simply put it as the last character."_ - Gimby, 2014-12-10. Stackoverflow. See, OP? I knew it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape the \ in Java, so replace all your \ with \  (mentioned by Hacketo)

Regex is regex, they don't get changed with respect to languages but yes, the way they are tested, changes..You just need to look into how to match a string with a regex in java.

Comment: It helped also what @Hacketo mentioned solves the problem

Comment: @ThakurArjunSingh yes, you see the core of regex doesn't change, it is actually how to use them with respect to different languages